# How to save XML file, which was passed by ASHX file, in PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, ashx

I don't know a lot about ashx files. And I have an ashx file, that takes an argument and returns XML document. So I want to write an PHP code that downloads these XML files and saves them in txt format. I tried doing this but it doesn't work =(

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++){
         $url = "localhost/getdata.ashx?id=".$i;
         $file = "files/".$i.".txt";
         file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($url));
    }
?>
```

Comment: `doesn't work` is not an error code. However probably you just need to add `http://` to your url

Comment: Ahh.. Sorry. The code works. But the generated file is empty.